# Loading Shopify Product Metafields in snippets

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to edit the default "Dawn" theme in my shopify store. My aim is to output product meta fields through a snippet. To do that, I have created a snippet called "color-swatches.liquid" which has the following code:

```
    <div class="sw-external-links modification">
        {%- if product.metafields.my_fields.current_product_color -%}
    </div>
```

When calling this snippet from product-card.liquid, I use the following liquid code:

```
{% render 'color-swatches', product: product_card_product %}
```

But I am not able to output the value of current_product_color metafield inside product.

If I paste the snipped code directly in product-card.liquid like this, it works:

```
{{ product_card_product.metafields.my_fields.current_product_color }}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I just want the snippet code to output the current_product_color metafield when I pass the product_card_product variable to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is not enough information in your question, I will try to help you the best I can.

1. In the snippet file (color-swatches.liquid), check if you're using the correct variable when accessing the product's metafield.
   If you render your snippet (in 'product-card.liquid') like this:
   `{% render 'color-swatches', MY_PRODUCT: product_card_product %}`,

   Then you should access the metafield (in 'color-swatches.liquid') like this:
   `{{ MY_PRODUCT.metafields.my_fields.current_product_color }}`
2. Check that if statement.

   - In liquid, prefer the `!= blank` syntax:
     `{%- if product.metafields.my_fields.current_product_color != blank -%}`
   - Check if the if statement even works.
     For that try to render the snippet outside the if.
3. If nothing is working double check yourself everywhere.
   Do this using `<script>console.log({{ YOUR_LIQUID_CODE | json }})</script>` and check the browser's console to see the logs.
   In both files, check the metafield, and the product.

Comment: Thank you. Reading your answer made me realize I was not calling the right object.

Comment: @Adi, seems you will be able to help me. I'm trying to display color swatches in collection. I have metaobject defined which has color and its name. Then I have defined a metafiled in variant and created link to metaobject. Now, I am trying to access hex value of color through variant.metafields.custom.color.value (variant is curret variant in for loop and custom is name space and color holds hex value) but instead of color I am getting gid links. Can you help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cyberspider789, I added a new question for this so others could find it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77740395/14399276, Tell me if the answer solved your problem