# Accessing metaobject referenced by variant metafield

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

This question was posted as a comment to a different question:

I'm trying to display color swatches in collection. I have metaobject defined which has color and its name. Then I have defined a metafield in variant and created link to metaobject.

Now, I am trying to access hex value of color through `variant.metafields.custom.color.value` (variant is current variant in for loop and custom is name space and color holds hex value) but instead of color I am getting gid links. @cyberspider789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the metaobject values by looping on them?

```
{% for metaobject in product.metafields.namespace.values %}
  {{ metaobject.field }}
  {{ metaobject.field.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Debug this by logging the values.